# how to pass argument "all" to column util-linux

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to apply some options of the `column` command of the util-linux to all my columns. I'm particularly interested in the `--table-right`, it works if a pass the number of the column. But I would like to pass a set and possibly even *all*.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/column.1.html

thanks

## edit

I found that `column` doesn't raise any error when passing a range of columns (i.e., 1,2,3,4,etc.) that doesn't match the number of columns in the file. Therefore, it is possible to use `seq` to make a default range and then pass it to `columns`.

```
column -t -s , -o ",  " -R $(seq -s , 1 1 50) file.csv
```

I'm accepting the answer as I think my question can either be solved with a feature request, as suggested, or with `seq` as above here.

Comment: IMHO you should post your edit as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit in the man page states:

```
OPTIONS         
       The argument columns for --table-* options is comma separated list of
       the column names as defined by --table-columns or it's column number
       in order as specified by input. It's possible to mix names and
       numbers.
```

to create a comma separated list of names and numbers. The man page does not list any shortcuts. You could try asking for a [feature request](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux) on the github page.

And provides an example in the form of 2 options:

```
sed 's/#.*//' /etc/fstab | column --table --table-columns 
SOURCE,TARGET,TYPE,OPTIONS,PASS,FREQ --table-right PASS,FREQ
```

You will need to write them all out as a list of numbers or list of names.

Mind that "util-linux" is not installed in Ubuntu by default. We use "BSD mainutils". Ours has less options.

Comment: Thanks, you are right about the util-linux, I compiled it and didn't realize that this makes my question kind of misplaced here. I found that `seq` may solve my problems at the moment, but thanks for suggesting the feature request, I'll think about it.